# Django MySql: how to choose storage engine for each model

Tags: mysql, django

**MySQL provides various storage engines for its tables as below:**

MyISAM

InnoDB

MERGE

MEMORY (HEAP)

ARCHIVE

CSV

FEDERATED

**how to use MyISAM for modelA and InnoDB for ModelB ?**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Note that if you use MyISAM for `ModelA`, foreign key constraints from `ModelB` to `ModelA` will not be enforced.

Comment: Thank you, But how can use various storage engines in django mysql for each model??

Comment: see docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#creating-your-tables

Comment: did you find a solution?